# How to change tooltip dataKey in recharts chart

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I would like to change tooltip dataKey in my tooltip. How can do it?

I would like to set to value `TOOLTIP_DATAKEY[activeLanguage]`

Which props should I use it on `<Tooltip />` imported from `import { Tooltip } from 'recharts';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [content](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Tooltip#content) prop

```
import { Tooltip } from 'recharts';

  ...

const CustomTooltip = () => <div>{TOOLTIP_DATAKEY[activeLanguage]}</div>;

  ...

<Tooltip
  content={<CustomTooltip/>}
/>
```